# CentOS7 でパッケージを yum remove した後もファイルが残っている

Tags: centos, yum

`yum remove php-*`したのに残る理由が見当つきません。ご存知でしたらよろしくお願いいたします。

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo yum remove php-*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Repository google-chrome is listed more than once in the configuration
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:7.1.24-1.el7.remi will be erased
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:7.1.24-1.el7.remi will be erased
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:7.1.24-1.el7.remi will be erased
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:7.1.24-1.el7.remi will be erased
---> Package php-json.x86_64 0:7.1.24-1.el7.remi will be erased
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:7.1.24-1.el7.remi will be erased
---> Package php-pecl-apcu.x86_64 0:5.1.13-1.el7.remi.7.1 will be erased
---> Package php-soap.x86_64 0:7.1.24-1.el7.remi will be erased
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:7.1.24-1.el7.remi will be erased
---> Package php-xmlrpc.x86_64 0:7.1.24-1.el7.remi will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

========================================================================================================================
 Package                     Arch                 Version                               Repository                 Size
========================================================================================================================
Removing:
 php                         x86_64               7.1.24-1.el7.remi                     @remi-php71               9.4 M
 php-cli                     x86_64               7.1.24-1.el7.remi                     @remi-php71                14 M
 php-common                  x86_64               7.1.24-1.el7.remi                     @remi-php71               7.9 M
 php-devel                   x86_64               7.1.24-1.el7.remi                     @remi-php71                10 M
 php-json                    x86_64               7.1.24-1.el7.remi                     @remi-php71                80 k
 php-mbstring                x86_64               7.1.24-1.el7.remi                     @remi-php71               2.8 M
 php-pecl-apcu               x86_64               5.1.13-1.el7.remi.7.1                 @remi-php71               221 k
 php-soap                    x86_64               7.1.24-1.el7.remi                     @remi-php71               616 k
 php-xml                     x86_64               7.1.24-1.el7.remi                     @remi-php71               855 k
 php-xmlrpc                  x86_64               7.1.24-1.el7.remi                     @remi-php71               165 k

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================
Remove  10 Packages

Installed size: 46 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
Exiting on user command
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
 yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx.2020-02-03.03-53.R7mS2G.yumtx
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ whereis php
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/lib64/php /etc/php.d /etc/php.ini /usr/include/php /usr/share/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ php -v
PHP 7.1.24 (cli) (built: Nov  7 2018 18:45:17) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yum remove` を実行した後にサマリーが表示されているかと思いますが、以下のプロンプトで `y` を入力しないと(デフォルトでは) `N` (=NO) で応答したものとみなされ、削除の動作は安全のためキャンセルされます。

```
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

確認画面を表示せずに(今回の場合なら)削除をすぐに実行するには、以下の様に `-y` オプションを付ける方法もあります。

```
# yum remove <PACKAGE_NAME> -y
```

Comment: 知らないでただエンター押してました。。ありがとうございます。